# How do I power down my Pi if I'm ssh'ed in?

Tags: filesystem, safety

I want to power down my Pi, but I don't have console access... I'm just logged in via ssh.

So I issue `sudo shutdown now` and it drops my connection almost instantly.  How long should I wait to unplug the device?  Are there any clues I can watch for with the on-board lights?

Answer (score 4):

You can wait for all the LED's to go off. Only the red LED(power LED) stays on. That's when the Pi has shutdown

Comment: If you don't have the ethernet plug connected, only the red is on while running too.  The green OK flickers when it shuts down tho, and it does seem to be finished when it returns to just the red PWR.

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi does not allow you to shut it down completely, unless you unplug the power. The best way to turn it off is by running `sudo shutdown -h now` and waiting until everything has been unloaded properly and then unplugging the device.

If you have no display I would recommend that you run the command and then wait a few minutes until you unplug the device.

Comment: I don't usually have to wait that long on mine until the root prompt pops up - whenever the red LED is the only one on, it's usually safe. 30 seconds, tops.

Comment: Yea, for sure. Unless there is an issue with the OS it shouldn't take long at all.